# Posicionar texto em TextViews e EditTexts com uma imagem como background?

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext, textview

Criei um app simples o qual possui apenas um **TextView** e um **EditText**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver **mudei** o background de ambos, até aí nenhum problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema aparece quando insiro textos, pois os mesmos ficam **mal posicionados no layout** tanto do TextView quanto do EditText:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até mesmo de maneiras diferentes...

Enfim, já tentei algumas formas para solucionar isso, inclusive selecionar **outros alinhamentos**, mas nada do comportamento mudar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que me informassem como fazer para que as caixas de textos ajam de forma similar a que exibirei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um **nine-patch** com a imagem presente na aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém já na preview do layout estranhei porque apareceu bugada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No resultado final no android emulator, foi **diferente**, mas igualmente **ruim**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem original possui as seguintes dimensões => 714x627... Fiz uma regra de 3, pois queria que a mesma tivesse 100 de largura.

Coloquei no **layout_width 100** e no **layout_heigth 88**.

O valor equivalente a 100 em altura, deu 87 e uns quebrados, pois fiz regra de 3, **aproximei para 88**. Mesmo assim, não deveria apresentar algo esdrúxulo assim...

A solução foi **diminuir o tamanho da imagem** e importar novamente para o android studio, aproveitei para colocar 2 pixels de largura e altura extras para não haver nenhum corte.

Comment: Não devia ter editado a pergunta com a solução, mas sim colocado como resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma de conseguir esse comportamento é a imagem de *background* ser um *nine-patch bitmap*.

Um [Nine-patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) é um bitmap que o Android redimensionará automaticamente para incluir o conteúdo da *View* à qual foi atribuído como *background*.

Ele é um PNG normal(a imagem usada como *background*) com uma borda extra de 1 pixel de espessura onde é definida a zona ajustável e a zona onde o conteúdo é colocado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Fonte: [Canvas and Drawables - Nine-patch.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)</sup>

Comment: A delimitações de margem e talz é até fácil de fazer, porém a imagem distorce completamente

Comment: diminuí o tamanho para o que eu setei no textview e resultou. obg!!!

Comment: Pode pôr a imagem na sua pergunta? Gostaria de tentar fazer com que ela não distorça.

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que dar um padding de, por exemplo, 10 DP no editText.

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Para centralizar, é só usar no xm ltambém um:

```
android:gravity"center"
```

Para quebrar linha em determinado número de caracteres, você terá de fazer isso via Java e adicionar um \n na string para quebrar a linha. Essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276639/java-how-to-split-a-string-by-a-number-of-characters) o ajudará.